# Get page UID by URL Alias (RealURL)

Tags: typo3, realurl

I need to get the UID by URL Alias. But I did not have any API in extension RealURL Is it possible to do this at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UID is set in the database table `tx_realurl_pathdata`. There you find the alias in field `pagepath`, the UID in `page_id`.